# can't run simple code in C language in visual studio code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, gcc-warning

I've got the problem for the C language still I can't run my code and see the output
after installing gcc and the code runner extension still, I can't run my simple code in Visual Studio code

my code is

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Enter your name: ");
    char name[100];
    scanf("%s", name);

    printf("Hello, %s! Welcome to the world of programming!", name);
    return 0;
}
```

show this warning
[the error popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEWqR.png)
and also in the terminal, I got this message in the terminal

```
     *  Executing task: C/C++: gcc.exe build active file 

Starting build...
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g C:\Users\mostafa\Desktop\hellowworld.c -o C:\Users\mostafa\Desktop\hellowworld.exe
cc1.exe: error: unrecognized command line option "-fdiagnostics-color=always"

Build finished with error(s).

 *  The terminal process failed to launch (exit code: -1). 
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

can anyone help me with this?

i installed gcc and code runner extention for visual studio code

Comment: Your gcc is WAY too old. Remove it and install the newest version, preferably with [msys2](https://www.msys2.org/).

Comment: Always use a maximum field width when reading strings with `scanf()` or use `fgets()` instead which requires it.

Comment: @AllanWind Sorry but I didn't catch that

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI it's not working still the same

Comment: `scanf("%s", name);` will result in a buffer overflow if user enters more than 99 characters.  Either use `scanf("%99s", name)` or `fgets(name, 100, stdin)`.  Also check the return value of these functions otherwise you may be operating on uninitialized data.

Comment: Please revise your question with proper debug information.  First you tried with gcc version x then you updated to version y.  You might want to double check `C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe --version` is y.

Comment: The current version of gcc that msys2 offers is 13.2. The last version of gcc that didn't recognise `-fdiagnostics-color` is about 4.8. So something is probably wrong at your end. Perhaps you didn't remove your current installation of gcc, and VSCode is still using it?